# RopeProgress Bar android studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use this RopeProgressBar in my application https://github.com/cdeange/RopeProgressBar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/deange/ropeprogressview/RopeProgressBar.java .

The creator uses  mRopeProgressBar.animateProgress(progress);

I am try to use a same code,but nothing works for me.

SplashActivity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwuB9.png)

XML file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8IQj.png)

Thank you in advance. Trying to solve this problem by myself about 3-4 hours.

Comment: "but nothing works for me". what exactly is happening? please copy and paste your code, and not show images. thanks.

Comment: Check answer please

Comment: answer? can u not edit your post?

Comment: it will say too much code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code you have the following:

```
mRopeProgressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
```

This needs to be:

```
mRopeProgressBar.animateProgress(progressStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.user.poiskovichok;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.deange.ropeprogressview.RopeProgressBar;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RopeProgressBar mRopeProgressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        mRopeProgressBar = findRopeProgressView(getWindow().getDecorView()); // equals findViewById



   new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 4;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mRopeProgressBar.animateProgress(progressStatus);
                        }


                    });

                    if (progressStatus > 100){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(500);


                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.getCause();
                }


            }




        }.start();



    }





    private RopeProgressBar findRopeProgressView(final View view) {
        if (view instanceof RopeProgressBar) {
            return (RopeProgressBar) view;

        } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup p = ((ViewGroup) view);
            View child;
            for (int i = 0; i < p.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if ((child = findRopeProgressView(p.getChildAt(i))) != null) {
                    return (RopeProgressBar) child;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: you are using setProgress.. not animateProgress

Comment: You are my savior!

Comment: plus, i would do if (progressStatus > 100) {startactivity();} NOT if (progressStatus == 101)

Comment: Just one more question, it seems strange, why app doesn't open a new activity ?

       if (progressStatus > 100){

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

Comment: I updated this answer, so you can check how my code looks right now

Comment: so it animates, reaches 100, and stays?

Comment: try progessStatus >= 100. do the math, 4, 8, 16, 20.... 100. The code is just saying if == 100...should be >= 100. :)

Comment: Haha, right now when application starts it opens MainActivity, without splash screen

Comment: Instantly opens MainActivity

Comment: makes sense. lifecycle of the activity. closing it probably pushed it to the main activity. uninstall, reinstall

Comment: youll have to do some debugging. add some break points in your splash activity to see what the progress is setting at... or if its even being hit.